# What does "stay free" mean?

Tags: terminology

I received a message from a player whom I lost to in a match of USF4.

He sent the following message through Steam:

> LowIQGod : you just got bodied son, get BTFO, stay free

What does "stay free" mean? I am having trouble understanding this, since it seems when I search it up it leads me to a company that sells feminine hygiene products.

Comment: easier to type than clear?

Comment: Would [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stay%20Free) help explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is apparently a phrase used within the Street Fighter/general FG community to mean that your opponent did poorly and should work on their performance. Basically, he insulted you and said you didn't do very well.

> An insult - Acknowledgment of one's poor performance. Telling someone that they will continue to perform at an unsatisfactory level if they dont put forth effort to get improve. - Usually used within the Street Fighter community.

Sources are [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stay%20Free&defid=5596543) (page is SFW but UD should be considered NSFW, in general) and [Shoryuken](http://forums.shoryuken.com/discussion/143641/basic-street-fighter-terminology-for-stream-announcers) (pretty much the biggest FGC forum out there).

Comment: Sidenote: I'd love to see the Etymology of this term. I can't think of any sensible connection between "Stay Free" and "You suck".

Comment: @MrLemon, given Shoryuken link says `FREE=when someone loses, they are FREE`. I think it's just free = not playing, so to stay free is like quit playing.

Comment: If I had to guess, it references fighting game tournaments and arcades where someone might be "free" for a match if they aren't currently playing against someone. In other words, the guy is telling you to stop playing the game.

Comment: I always thought it came out of the 'Free to play' vs 'paid subscription', as in *"Don't waste your money, you're not good enough to bother paying for this game"*

Comment: I think this refers to arcades where you have to pay money to compete. If you play against a scrub you basically play for free, as they have to provide the money for a new round. There is another term 'to be on sale', which means you are still better, but your opponent is quite good too.

Comment: This is late but it refers to the player being so bad they are essentially a "free" win if you play against them. Similarly in games that use an ELO ranking (starcraft, league of legends etc.) someone might instead say you are "freELO", as in free ELO ranking.